# Python OKTA and Salesforce

Tags: python, salesforce, okta, okta-api

apologies is this is very basic, but I'm very new to Python (and programming in general) and need some help getting data out of Salesforce that requires SSO authentication through OKTA.

My organization just decided to enforce SSO with OKTA after a couple people fell for the most basic of phishing emails. Previously, we had the option to use our OKTA credentials to access salesforce but could also use salesforce credentials on login.salesforce.com I had been using simple salesforce to access salesforce (using userID, password, and token). I downloaded data using SOQL queries, did a lot of data cleanup and aggregation in Python, then published to Tableau server. With SSO enabled simple salesforce clearly no longer works.

Again, apologies if this is straight forward but I can't find anything that is helpful for someone as.... green in programming as I am.

If anyone has any resources they could point me to, or libraries that would help me move in the right direction it would be greatly greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with `simple_salesforce` by itself. You need to execute an OAuth login flow to get a valid Session Id, and `simple_salesforce` does not support OAuth.

One option is to authenticate via the `sfdx` CLI, which *does* support OAuth, and use its [data commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm) to do your extractions, then postprocess in Python.

Another is to use another library, or do your OAuth authentication out-of-band, and then provide your access token directly to `simple_salesforce`. This is going to be a bit more complicated and require you to write some code.

A last possibility (*disclaimer*: I am on the team building this product) is to use [CumulusCI](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io) to do your authentication and write your data extract/manipulation as a CumulusCI task. This will also involve writing/learning new code but the authentication would be handled for you, and CumulusCI comes with some Bulk and REST API primitives to do data extraction out of the box.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I'll start looking into the options you suggested. Really appreciate just having a starting point and a direction to explore!